# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Input resource must exist (reader is in 'strict' mode): class path resource

Tags: java, spring, batch-processing, spring-batch

This is the form of my project

```
src
   main
        ressources
                   applicationContext.xml
target
upload
       pharmacies.txt
```

And this is the Spring Batch Reader

```html
  <property name="resource" value="./upload/pharmacies.txt" />
  <property name="lineMapper">
   <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
    <property name="lineTokenizer">
    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
     <property name="delimiter" value=","/>
     <property name="names" value="nom,telephone,adresse,Latitude,Longitude" />
    </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="fieldSetMapper">
     <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper">
      <property name="targetType" value="model.Pharmacie" />
     </bean>
    </property>
   </bean>
  </property>
 </bean>
```

this is the batch that I run

```html
public class BatchPharmacie {

 public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception {
  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext cpt = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
  //cpt.start();
  JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) cpt.getBean("jobLauncher");
  Job job = (Job) cpt.getBean("importPharmacies");
  //JobParameters parameter = new JobParametersBuilder().addDate("date", new Date())
  //   .addString("input.file", "C:/envdev/travail/in/personnes.txt").toJobParameters();
  jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
 }

}
```

And I get this error

**java.lang.IllegalStateException: Input resource must exist (reader is in 'strict' mode): class path resource**

Comment: try prefix path resource with file://

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using a relative URL like that for your input location in your configuration file.  What happens when you fully qualify it as well as adding the file:// as Luca mentions?

Comment: ten thousand views and no one thinks it's a good question.  Well, you got my vote at least!

Comment: I ran into this issue when working with Michael Minella's excellent Spring Batch book using IntelliJ.  In IntelliJ, right click on src/main/resources directory and select "Mark Directory as -> Resources Root".  

Strange thing is that I tried "Mark Directory as -> Unmark Resources Root", restarted IntelliJ, cleaned up all IntelliJ files to reproduce original issue and was not able to re-produce it.  I'm thinking it is just an IntelliJ quirk that resources was not in the classpath.

Answer (score 5):

You might have got the solution by now. This error troubled me for some time. That is when I browsed spring batch documentation on ClassPathResource. It says, ClassPathResource represents a resource which should be obtained from the classpath. 
Use FileSystemResource or UrlResource if your resource file resides outside your classPath.

Reference: 
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html